# REST PUT with external file JSON to httpClient Java?

Tags: java, json, rest, put

I need to translate this for example :

```
curl -X PUT -u ident:pass -H "Content-Type : application/json" --data-binary @G:\jonJob.json "http://localhost:8080/jobs/"
```

(this works).

in java with httpClient. I have try a lot of things but nothing work.. 
Someone could help me please ?

What I've tried :

```
public class PostFile {
  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


        CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("ident", "pass");
        provider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider).build();


    HttpPut httppost = new HttpPut("http://localhost:8080/jobs/");
    File file = new File("G:/jsonJob.json");
    HttpEntity httpEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create().addBinaryBody("file", file, ContentType.create("application/json"), file.getName()).build();

    httppost.setEntity(httpEntity);
    System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
    if (resEntity != null) {
      System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
    }
    if (resEntity != null) {
      resEntity.consumeContent();
    }

    httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
  }
}
```

Result : "HTTP/1.1 415 Not supported type" (unsupported media type)

Comment: Hi, thank's for your answer, I have edit my post with more informations (sry for my bad english)

Comment: dont use MME  'multipart' to replace curl @  with a post. Use a ByteArrayEntity. and get the header set :   request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json") ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your http req headers   -H you have java runnable imple with interceptor:

public void run() {

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setConnectionManager(YourConnectionMgr.getInstance())
        .addInterceptorLast(new HttpRequestInterceptor() {
            public void process(
                    final HttpRequest request, 
                    final HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException { 

                    if (request.getRequestLine().getMethod() == "POST"){                                
                        request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json") ;
```

see [examples here](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/examples.html) to figure out 'connectionManager'

for simple auth, [add this](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientAuthentication.java)

to map in memory and POST a file [see answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744710/posting-base64-encoded-video-files-using-httpclient/26748090#26748090)

Note, you will eventually want some kind of async http client for java , you can google for that. The apache examples like in the link provided are mostly blocking network calls AFAIK